# Autolayout constraints warning "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint"

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am setting some specifics constraints for iPhone 4 when the app is ran on this device. Everything look great in terms of alignment and everything.

But, I am getting an error for all my constraints that is trying to recover them by breaking the constraints.

This method gets call in my viewDidLoad when it detects if its an iPhone 4

```
- (void) addConstraints {

    // removing automatic system constraints
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(appBackground, myCustomer, myItemDetails, myItemQuantity, myItemPrice, myNext, myBtn); // UIImageView, UITextField, UIButton

    for (UIView *view in [views allValues]) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    }

    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"width": @210.0, @"height": @42.0, @"verticalSpacing": @34};

    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[appBackground]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[appBackground]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views]];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(85)-[myCustomer(==height)]-(verticalSpacing)-[myItemDetails(==height)]-(verticalSpacing)-[myItemQuantity(==height)]-(verticalSpacing)-[myItemPrice(==height)]-(18)-[myNext(==35)]-(71.5)-[myBtn(==50)]-(7.5)-|"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:metrics
                                                                      views:views]];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[myCustomer(==width)]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:metrics
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[myItemDetails(==width)]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:metrics
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[myItemQuantity(==width)]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:metrics
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[myItemPrice(==width)]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:metrics
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-78-[myNext(==173)]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:metrics
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-11.5-[myBtn(==54)]-|"
                                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                                     metrics:metrics
                                                                                                       views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

}
```

Error!

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb8282f0 H:|-(50)-[UITextField:0xb823fc0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb828320 H:[UITextField:0xb823fc0(210)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82be10 H:[UITextField:0xb823fc0]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d3d0 H:|-(78)-[UIButton:0xb82ad50]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d420 H:[UIButton:0xb82ad50(173)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d450 H:[UIButton:0xb82ad50]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d450 H:[UIButton:0xb82ad50]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-08-03 14:03:29.239 iReceipt[2886:607] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb8282f0 H:|-(50)-[UITextField:0xb823fc0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb828320 H:[UITextField:0xb823fc0(210)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82be10 H:[UITextField:0xb823fc0]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d480 H:|-(11.5)-[UIButton:0xb820120]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82e390 H:[UIButton:0xb820120(54)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82e3c0 H:[UIButton:0xb820120]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82e3c0 H:[UIButton:0xb820120]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>
```

Please let me know if you guys need more information..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These three constraints:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb8282f0 H:|-(50)-[UITextField:0xb823fc0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb828320 H:[UITextField:0xb823fc0(210)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82be10 H:[UITextField:0xb823fc0]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
```

dictate that the superview be 50 + 210 + 20 == 280 points wide.

These three constraints:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d3d0 H:|-(78)-[UIButton:0xb82ad50]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d420 H:[UIButton:0xb82ad50(173)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb82d450 H:[UIButton:0xb82ad50]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xb82f360 )>"
```

dictate that the same superview be 78 + 173 + 20 == 271 points wide.

Obviously, those can't both be true at the same time. You need to decide what you really want to happen here. We can't read your mind and neither can UIKit.

Usually, you don't set a width constraint on a button; you let it use its intrinsic size with appropriate priorities for content hugging and compression resistance. Also, you may not wish to set hard spacing on either side of the button. Either let that spacing vary without constraint so the button can be its intrinsic size, lower the priority of that constraint so it's optional, or make an inequality so you have a minimum spacing but not an exact spacing.

Comment: so, one of the problem is when I set my vertical constraints 'V:|-(85)-[myCustomer(==height)]-(verticalSpacing)-[myItemDetails(==height)]-(verticalSpacing)-[myItemQuantity(==height)]-(verticalSpacing)-[myItemPrice(==height)]-(18)-[myNext(==35)]-(71.5)-[myBtn(==50)]-(7.5)-|' all at once?

Comment: The problem you posted is with your horizontal constraints, not your vertical constraints. You'll have a similar problem vertically if your superview isn't exactly `85+3*(height+verticalSpacing)+height+18+35+71.5+50+7.5` points high, though. You should build as much flexibility into your constraints as possible, as Ken mentioned.

Comment: That part of your code is about the vertical layout while the conflict is due to the horizontal layout. The `UIButton` seems to be your `myNext` given the width. The `UITextField` could be any of them since they are constrained the same way. I have to say, though, that you seem to be over-constraining in general. I don't know what the relationship of the superview is to the screen, but you are dictating everything down to the point. There's no flexibility here for handing different screen sizes or orientations, etc.

Comment: ok. but I don't actually want to provide more flexibility because I won't be supporting landscape mode and I only want the fields and buttons to have a exact width and height when is run on iPhone 4 to match my UI design

Comment: Then why are you using auto layout?

Comment: To support iPhone 4 and iPad x1 or x2 mode, because it works perfectly on iPhone 5 because how I created on Storyboard but when it runs in iPhone 4 everything gets all over the place.. so, I did a bit of research and I was suppose to use Auto layout for this..

Comment: Do you suggest a different approach? @KenThomases

Comment: I don't do iOS development and don't know what's required to support those devices. However, I doubt very much that using auto layout in a way that doesn't allow any flexibility helps in any way. It's no better than the old autoresizing masks (springs and struts) approach, and arguably worse. I'm sure that using auto layout in a sensible way would be fine, of course.

Comment: Of the many views on the screen I can't identify which exact view is this. What is `0xb823fc0` I initially thought it's the pointer to the textField (attempting to print its text), but my Xcode shows me it's of type `long`

Comment: Well, Xcode's not going to know what the underlying type was after a variable has been printed to the console or whatever. Anyway, yes, `0xb823fc0` in this case is the address of the view (a text field).

Answer (score 3):

You are constraining your views too much. You must always leave for example one of leftmargin, width and rightmargin flexible, and let the autolayout engine stretch that one.

A single dash without any number means default distance, which is 20 pixels. So, if you remove your trailing constraints on

```
@"H:|-78-[myNext(==173)]-|"
@"H:|-11.5-[myBtn(==54)]-|"
```

and change them to

```
@"H:|-78-[myNext(==173)]"
@"H:|-11.5-[myBtn(==54)]"
```

the layout engine will then stretch the rightmargin of the button to make it fit the
containing view. There are of course other ways of loosening up these constraints, all depending on your design goals.

Personally, I never use the standard API:s for autolayout anymore. I use the library [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout), which abstracts autolayout wonderfully!

Comment: The lack of a dash means "zero distance", not "arbitrary distance". Your change doesn't make anything more flexible. You could just leave off the trailing relationship entirely if you want it to be flexible (e.g. `@"H:|-78-[myNext(==173)]"`).